# How to create custom loader as shared component? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, widget, loader

I need to create custom loader on whole page with half-transparent background. It need to be as shared Widget because i need to have a possibility to start it on different pages.

Please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to build something like this https://pub.dev/packages/modal_progress_hud (you can look at his git repo).

The way to reuse a Widget is very simple. Just create it on it's own `.dart` file. Then just import it where you want to use (In the same way you import the material).

Exemple:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'components/buttons.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_loader) as a dependency. It is fully customizable and you can use it on different pages if required.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     //// Wrap your body in a stack
     body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text("Lorem Ipsum"), //// Your page content
        ),
        //// Put the loader widget at the end of the stack. You can set it to appear based on a boolean. E.g. a loading flag.
        EasyLoader(image: AssetImage('assets/loading.png'),) 
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```